# Add layout to image files in jekyll

Tags: jekyll

I want to make a photo gallery with Jekyll where each image has its own page. Ideally I don't want to have to make a .md page for each image manually as there are 700+ images.
Each image should use the "photo.html" layout I created.

I've tried the following solution

```
# _config.yml
defaults:
  -
    scope:
      path: "photos"
    values:
      layout: photo
```

but this doesn't work, opening a photo still only shows the image and not the surrounding HTML. How do I work this out?

Answer (score 0):

Jekyll is a static site generator, so all pages must be created during the site generation. But you can automate creation of .md page for each file.

Specifically:

1. Have a script to create `{photo_name}.md` file in /photo_pages directory for each photo in `/photos`. Run the script after adding/removing any photo.

```rb
photos_dir = 'photos'
output_dir = 'photo_pages'

FileUtils.mkdir_p(output_dir)

Dir.foreach(photos_dir) do |photo_path|
  next if photo_path == '.' or photo_path == '..'

  photo_name = File.basename(photo_path, '.*')
  photo_page_content = <<~MARKDOWN
    ---
    layout: photo
    title: #{photo_name}
    photo_url: /#{photos_dir}/#{File.basename(photo_path)}
    ---
  MARKDOWN

  output_file = File.join(output_dir, "#{photo_name}.md")
  File.write(output_file, photo_page_content)
end
```

2. Add a collection to `_config.yml`:

```
collections:
  photo_pages:
    output: true
```

3. Then you can have a gallery page with links to each photo page:

```html
{% for photo in site.photo_pages %}
  <a href={{ photo.url }}> Link to page with the photo</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Do Jekyll hooks help with this issue? I'd like to have the pages generated along with the site, since that's the purpose of an SSG. Thank you for your answer by the way

Comment: Yes, you can use jekyll hooks. You can wrap the script into ruby function and register a hook, eg:
```
require_relative '../generate_photos'

Jekyll::Hooks.register :site, :pre_render do |site, payload|
  generate_photos
end
```
Just remember to put the hook file into `_plugins` dir.